# How to open notebook saved in Files, Google Colab

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have cloned a Github repository into Google Colab. Repository contains a Notebook. I want to open it in Google Colab. My question is that how I can open Notebook saved in Files?

[image]

I know that I can use Open Notebook / Github. But, when I open a notebook by this way, I cannot import other python files or data from the Repository.

[image]

I prefer to avoid Copy/Paste from Github notebook into Colab notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to add this line to import other python, data files.

```
! npx degit TropComplique/mtcnn-pytorch -f
```

If you really want to work on the same data, without copying, you need to store them in Google Drive. Then, extract file_id of a notebook with `xattr`, and open it using a link `colab.research.google.com/drive/{file_id}`

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean instead of using "!git clone URL", I use "! npx degit "?

Comment: Yes, it will get the content inside. No need to %cd. Also faster.